# g++ conio.h: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, g++

I'm trying to write a program with g++ that uses `conio.h` header.
What I'm actually trying to do is calling `gotoxy` function which I used in Borland compiler and windows OS.

So the first question is: is there a `gotoxy` function or equivalent in g++?

Second: why can't I include conio.h? I read some stuff that said I should install `libstdc++ package`, I tried but it seems that I already have it (it's accompanied by gcc).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent for g++. `conio.h` is specific to some DOS compilers. But you can get what you want using `ncurses` library, its functions are similar to ones in `conio.h`.

Here's a link to a very elaborate tutorial: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Answer (score 5):

`conio.h` is specific to the Windows console environment.  Use the `curses` or `ncurses` library on Unix; the appropriate function is `mvcur()` in the low level interface and `wmove()` in the virtual window interface.

Answer (score 2):

Well its not in gcc but it does come with MiniGW. It is specific to Windows.

For linux you want the ncurses library.