# undefined reference to gotoxy in C

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am trying to write a program in C language(code::blocks in windows).
I have added below header files, it compiles with no error, but when it comes to run the code it throws an error undefined reference to gotoxy.
Find the full code.
Error comes where ever I have gotoxy statements.

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<conio.h>
# include<malloc.h>
# include<stdlib.h>
# include<windows.h>
#include<dos.h>
struct node
{  int data;
    struct node *link;
};
void append(struct node **,int);
void in_begin(struct node **,int);
void del(struct node **,int);
void in_middle(struct node **,int,int);
int count(struct node *);
void display(struct node *);
char ans;
int main()
{   struct node *p;  /* p can be said as the head or a start ptr */
     p=NULL;
     /* Printing the menu */
     int num,loc;
     char choice;
     do
     { //clrscr();
        printf("PROGRAM TO IMPLEMENT SINGLY LINKED LIST ");
        printf("\n=====================================");
        printf("\n\n1.Create \\ Appending The List");
        printf("\n2.Insert Node At Begining");
        printf("\n3.Insert Node In Middle");
        printf("\n4.Deleting a  Node");
        printf("\n5.Counting The No Of Nodes");
        printf("\n6.Displaying the list");
        printf("\n7.Exit");
        oper:
        gotoxy(1,15);printf("                                          ");
        gotoxy(1,11);printf("\n\nEnter ur Choice : ");
        choice=getch();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case '1':
            //  char ans;
              do
             {  printf("Enter any number : ");
                 scanf("%d",&num);
                 append(&p,num);
                 printf("Enter more (y/n) :");
                 fflush(stdin);
                 ans=getchar();
              }while(ans !='n');
             break;
             case '2':
             printf("Enter The Data : ");
             scanf("%d",&num);
             in_begin(&p,num);
             break;

             case '3':
             printf("\nEnter The Position :");
             scanf("%d",&loc);
             printf("\nEnter The Data : ");
             scanf("%d",&num);
             in_middle(&p,loc,num);
             break;

             case '4':
             printf("\nEnter The Data u Want To Delete : ");
             scanf("%d",&num);
             del(&p,num);
             break;

             case '5':
             printf("\nThe No Of Nodes Are %d",count(p));
             getch();
             break;

             case '6':
             display(p);
             getch();
             break;

             case '7':
             printf("\n\nQuiting.......");
             getch();
             exit(0);
             break;

             default:
             gotoxy(1,15);printf("Invalid choice.Please Enter Correct Choice");
             getch();
             goto oper;

        }

     }while(choice !=7);
return 0;
}

void append(struct node **q,int num)
{   struct node *temp,*r;
     temp = *q;
     if(*q==NULL)
     {   temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
          temp->data=num;
          temp->link=NULL;
          *q=temp;
     }
     else
     {  temp = *q;
         while(temp->link !=NULL)
         {  temp=temp->link;
         }
         r = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         r->data=num;
         r->link=NULL;
         temp->link=r;
     }
}

void display(struct node *q)
{     if(q==NULL)
        {  printf("\n\nEmpty Link List.Can't Display The Data");
            getch();
            goto last;
        }
      while(q!=NULL)
        {  printf("\n%d",q->data);
            q=q->link;
        }
     last:
     ;
}

int count(struct node *q)
{  int c=0;
    if(q==NULL)
    { printf("Empty Link List.\n");
      getch();
      goto last;
    }
    while(q!=NULL)
    {   c++;
         q=q->link;
    }
    last:
    return c;

}

void in_begin(struct node **q,int num)
{  struct node *temp;
    if(*q==NULL)
    {  printf("Link List Is Empty.Can't Insert.");
        getch();
        goto last;
    }
    else
    {   temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         temp->data=num;
         temp->link=*q;
         *q=temp;  /* pointing to the first node */
     }
     last:
     getch();
}

void in_middle(struct node **q,int loc,int num)
{  struct node *temp,*n;
    int c=1,flag=0;
    temp=*q;
    if(*q==NULL)
    {  printf("\n\nLink List Is Empty.Can't Insert.");
        getch();
        goto last;
    }
    else
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {  if(c==loc)
        {  n = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            n->data=num;
            n->link=temp->link;
            temp->link=n;
            flag=1;
        }
        c++;
        temp=temp->link;
     }
     if(flag==0)
     { printf("\n\nNode Specified Doesn't Exist.Cant Enter The Data");
        getch();
     }
     else
     { printf("Data Inserted");
        getch();
     }
     last:
     getch();
}

void del(struct node**q,int num)
{    if(*q==NULL)
      {  printf("\n\nEmpty Linked List.Cant Delete The Data.");
          getch();
          goto last;
      }
      else
      {
      struct node *old,*temp;
      int flag=0;
      temp=*q;
      while(temp!=NULL)
      {  if(temp->data==num)
          {   if(temp==*q)         /* First Node case */
                *q=temp->link;  /* shifted the header node */
                else
                old->link=temp->link;

                free(temp);
                flag=1;
            }
            else
            {  old=temp;
                temp=temp->link;
            }
         }
         if(flag==0)
            printf("\nData Not Found...");
         else
              printf("\nData Deleted...Tap a key to continue");
              getch();
        }
        last:
        getch();
      }
```

Please help me.

Comment: You probably need to link the library providing that function. On Linux that would be `libncurses` but I have no idea for Windows.

Comment: What library is it implemented in?  Are you linking it?  Adding header file `#include` statements is not going to solve a link error.

Comment: codeblock doesnt have conio header

Comment: @Rohit: Please find the updated question

Comment: isnt the problem still same? if you have to use conio use another compiler.

Comment: U ahvent updated the question only code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you're facing isn't related to `Code::Blocks`, it's related to the compiler it's using (MinGW by default), and it's because that function isn't standard and wasn't implemented in that compiler. I'm not sure if Borland still provides `conio.h`, but you could try [this one](http://conio.sourceforge.net/)  for `MinGW`.

Have a look at this http://projectsofashok.blogspot.in/2010/05/gotoxy-in-codeblocks.html

You can also try the below snippet, **this will work in GCC**

```
#include<stdio.h>
//gotoxy function
void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
}
main ()
{
gotoxy(25,50); //reposition cursor
printf("hello world"); //display text
}
```

You can also have a look at [NCURSES](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

Answer (score 3):

**Code::Blocks(MinGW) doesnt have conio.h header file. So you cant use** `gotoxy()`

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>     
    main()
    {     
       gotoxy(10, 10);     
       printf("C program to change cursor position.");     
       getch();
       return 0;
    }
```

this works fine in C. but not in code blocks.
The problem you're facing isn't related to Code::Blocks, it's related to the compiler it's using (MinGW by default), and it's because that function isn't standard and wasn't implemented in that compiler.
try using these:

```
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, TL);
HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

or use Borland C which supports conio.h. For getting it Visit the [LINK](http://conio.sourceforge.net/)

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<conio.h>  // you cant use conio.h
# include<malloc.h>
# include<stdlib.h>
# include<windows.h>
```

Comment: i cant find any `gotoxy()` now

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth, here are some Windows versions of the old Borland functions I wrote maybe a decade ago.

```
/* console_functions.h */


#ifndef __WINAPI_CONSOLE_WRAPPER_H
#define __WINAPI_CONSOLE_WRAPPER_H

void init_console_functions (void);

void gotoxy (int x, int y);

void clrscr (void);

char getch  (void);


#endif /* __WINAPI_CONSOLE_WRAPPER_H */


/* console_functions.c */
#include "ConsoleFunctions.h"                      
#include <windows.h>

static HANDLE hStdout;
static HANDLE hStdin;
static CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
static const COORD startCoords = {0,0};


void init_console_functions (void)
{
  hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdout, &csbi);
}

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
  COORD coord;

  coord.X = x;
  coord.Y = y;

  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout,coord);
}


void clrscr(void)
{
  DWORD dummy;

  FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdout,
                             ' ',
                             csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y,
                             startCoords,
                             &dummy);    
  gotoxy(0,0);
}


char getch(void)
{
  INPUT_RECORD inp_rec;
  DWORD        bytes_read;
  BOOL         success;

  do
  {
    success = PeekConsoleInput(hStdin, &inp_rec, 1, &bytes_read);
    FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hStdin);
  } while(!success || inp_rec.EventType != KEY_EVENT || bytes_read==0);

  return (char)inp_rec.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;
}
```

Comment: Why is the code in `getch` polling using `PeekConsoleInput` instead of calling [ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) (which blocks when no input is available)? The code also returns a character whenever a key is *released*.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things for such kinds of questions in C
1) you have to have the proper header with the proper prototp  (this i conio.h)
2) you have to have the proper library to link against in this case probably something along libconio.lib

You then have to include the proper header and you have to inform  the linker against which libraries you like to link.

The link commands in gcc e.g are -L and -l and both are needed to use conio.

See also: [g++ conio.h: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565924/g-conio-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

it is error because there is something missing that can handle the gotoxy try this code

```
int gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    COORD coord = {x,y};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),coord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code blocks GUI doesn't work gotoxy()
so you make function it here....

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<windows.h>

    void gotoxy(int a, int b)    
    {
        COORD c;

        c.X=a;        
        c.Y=b;

        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);    
    }

    int main()
    {    
        gotoxy(5, 66);
        printf("hello");
        getch();
    }
```