# Using conio2 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio, conio

I'm trying to use `conio2.h` to make a game for a college homework, but I can't find how to use it with Visual Studio 2010 Professional in Windows 7. All the guides I've found direct me to use DevCPP or another compiler/IDE, but that isn't a option for me.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: `conio2.h` [is devcpp's implementation of `conio.h`](http://conio.sourceforge.net/docs/html/conio2_8h.html#_details). Just use regular `conio.h` in visual studio.

Comment: I have to use conio.h conio2.h because i need to implement a arkanoid game with pure C. So, i need to use it in Visual Studio to delivery it to professor. I think doing system command is not a good way to implement conio2.h functions that isn't exists with conio.h of VS.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, and your experience, you might be able to directly call the Windows API [console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). These are called by the conio functions. An example of how to implement gotoxy() and clrscr() can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9783195/584518).

Answer (score 1):

conio was deprecated and is useless in visual studio. you could try PDcurses.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy no, conio.h has almost none of the functions he is expecting. He cannot set the cursor position or individual characters, or even clear the screen through it. It exists and is there, but take a look at it; it is useless.