# gotoxy() in C not C++ undefined reference conio.h

Tags: c, mingw

I can't use C++ syntax like `cout`, so I've tried using `<conio.h>` but it still says

> undefined reference to '_gotoxy'

What's the problem? Everyone says that `conio.h` its not in K&R either because it isn't a standard library. Anyone got an idea?

I am using MinGW and command prompt.

Comment: "undefined reference" is a linker error. You may need to tell it to link whatever library contains `gotoxy`.

Comment: If you get compilation/linker errors, please add them (verbatim) to the question. Also add the command line (if any) you use to compile/link.

Comment: @DanielFischer isnt gcc filename.c -o outputname enough?

Comment: @vincentbelkin Not if you need to link libraries beyond the default. E.g. if you use functions from `math.h`, you have to pass `-lm` to link with the math library.

Comment: @DanielFischer where exactly do i put -lm conio.h where? with the gcc filename.......?

Comment: @vincentbelkin: `gotoxy` is not defined in conio.h from MinGW... Do you try to use a third party lib? `gotoxy` remembers me the old times of Turbo Pascal with the CRT unit :)

Comment: @vincentbelkin The `-lm` was for the math library, that has nothing to do with `conio.h`. I have no idea what that library might be called. The command line would be something like `gcc -o executable_name source.c -llib_name`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined reference to gotoxy in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782287/undefined-reference-to-gotoxy-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linking you need to add the ncurses library:

```
$ gcc my-source.c -o my-program -lncurses
```

That last flag to the command line above (`-lncurses`) is what tells the compiler to link (`-l`) with the ncurses library.