# How to include gotoxy() function in a program in visual?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am unable to use `gotoxy()`, `window()`, `sleep()`, `delay()`, `delline()` functions in Visual Studio 2012.

Is there any alternative to these functions which I can use

Comment: You're looking for something like the Windows [console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined reference to gotoxy in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782287/undefined-reference-to-gotoxy-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

With Visual 2008 express, you can find Sleep in windows.h.  (Sleep with a upper case S !)

It may be the same for 2012.

I don't know the other functions.