# Conio.o unavailable in Dev C - C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, colors, turbo-c

I want to include Borland functions in dev compiler on windows. I searched Dev site and found the solution: to include conio.o.
But i am using DEV 4.9.9.2 Compiler (Beta) and i cannot find anything named conio.o in thier folder
please instruct me on how to include borland functions in any way.
It doesnt matter if it is through some other way what i want to use functions like 'sleep()', changing background or text color, 'gotoxy()'
Dev Site reffering to this problem: http://www.bloodshed.net/dev/faq.html

Comment: The compiler is called GCC, Dev is just the IDE around it. I don't know if someone ever developed a full-scale conio library for GCC. But you can achieve everything conio does through Windows API calls. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782287/undefined-reference-to-gotoxy-in-c/9783195#9783195) of how to implement some of the most common functions.

Comment: Agreed. Don't bother learning deprecated functionality.

Comment: When *that* Dev-C++ site talks about an update released on February 21, it's talking about **2005**. The compiler it comes with (GCC) has been updated at least *50 times* since then. Please choose a newer tool.

Answer (score 0):

The source files for the *conio.o* file that came with older versions of Dev-C++ have since been deleted, but you can recover them from [the CVS attic on SourceForge](http://dev-cpp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dev-cpp/V5/source/conio/?hideattic=0).